# Symfony: Update entity without related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I need to update entity (PostMeta) without related entity (Post). The + code looks like this:

```
$post = $postRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $postId]);

$postMeta = new PostMeta;
$postMeta->setPost($post);
$postMeta->setMetaKey('views');
$postMeta->setMetaValue($count + 1);
$postMeta->setUser(null);
$postMeta->setDate(new \DateTime());

$this->_em->persist($postMeta);
$this->_em->flush($postMeta);
```

How to persist PostMeta entity, but not update Post entity?

Comment: Why Post entity is updated here? you just set the relation

Comment: Post is not updated here..

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Why do you think it is updated? Can you show the actual SQL queries that are executed with your example code when `flush()` is called?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your Entity `PostMeta`, in `$post` attribute remove if is there any `cascade={persist}`

Answer (score 0):

you do not update POST you only set postMeta post attribute so you can do your update with postMeta and Post will not be in any case modify